# How can I enable Django to send emails?

Tags: postfix, smtp, python, django

I have a Debian server (Linux www 4.5.0-x86_64-linode65 #2 SMP Mon Mar 14 18:01:58 EDT 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux), and postfix is installed.

It is working at least far enough that if, from the command line, I type "echo foo | Mail ______________", it behaves predictably well and I receive the test email without problems.

**However, the Django mail service on my Pinax installation seems to be a noop.** I have the following one-minute cron entry:

```
* * * * * /home/cjsh/bin/______________-mail
```

The referenced script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
source /home/cjsh/______________-env/bin/activate
cd /home/cjsh/______________
python manage.py send_mail >> /tmp/______________-mail.out 2>&1
```

When I do a tail -f on the output file, and I do not do anything to generate a new email, the output makes sense:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
acquiring lock...
acquired.
releasing lock...
released.

0 sent; 0 deferred;
done in 0.01 seconds
```

And if I request a password reset to trigger sending a test email, the output looks like *that* is being handled appropriately, too:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
acquiring lock...
acquired.
sending message 'Password reset e-mail sent' to _________________
releasing lock...
released.

1 sent; 0 deferred;
done in 0.15 seconds
```

But here's the problem. Although it reports an email is successfully sent, I have never seen an email sent by Pinax, including Gmail searches for "in:anywhere".

What, if anything, can I do to either:

1. Install packages so that Pinax will have everything it needs for routine Django "python manage.py send_mail" invocations to work, or
2. Configure Pinax to go through my pobox or gmail account, or
3. Do something else so that routine email notifications from Pinax go out?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Emails started going out as soon as I replaced postfix with sendmail. Additional configuration may be appropriate, but my site has passed the smoke test.